# Temperature/heat equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

I solved this problem
$$\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
u_{t}=ku_{xx}, & x\in(0,1), t>0 \\
u(0,t)=2, u(1,t)=3, & t>0 \\
u(x,0)=x^{2}+x+2, & x\in(0,1)
\end{array}\right.$$
and I got this
$$u(x,t)=2+x+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} c_{n}e^{-n^{2}\pi^{2}kt}\sin(n\pi x)$$

About this, I had no problem.

**My questions are** (actually, my teacher's questions):

**1-** After a long time, is there any point in the bar which the temperature is $10^ºC$? If yes or no, why?

**2-** Can I use the fact that both temperatures in the bar's extremes are less than 10? If not, how could I answer this?

Comment: After a long time means a large value of $t$. You can try to determine the solution in the limit $t\to\infty$.

Comment: I know, but for $t\to\infty$ I get $u(x,t)=2+x$, and so what? haha I just solve $u(x,t)=10=\Rightarrow x=8$ and it can't be because $x\in(0,1)$?

Comment: That argument sounds fine to me, I'm not sure what else the teacher could be asking for here. When saying "after a long time" one is basically asking for the equilibrium solution. I guess one can argue physically for why this has to be so and if needed show rigorously that there is no time alltogeather where $u=10$ by bounding the solution (with knowledge of the $c_n$'s). This is more work though.

Comment: There is a theorem which states that any solution of the heat equation in a region of $(x,t)$ must have its extrema (minima and maxima) on the boundary of that region. In this case, the region is $(x,t)\in [0,1]\times[0,\infty)$. On $(x=0,t>0)$ the solution is fixed at 2. On $(x=1,t>0)$ the solution is fixed at 3. On $(x,t=0)$ the maximum value of 4 occurs at $x = 1$. Thus 4 is the maximum value of $u(x,t)$ for all $x$ and $t$.

Comment: @JohnBarber Ahh the maximum principle. That is a very good answer to this question as it addresses all possible interpretations. You should write it up.

Comment: @Winther That was what I was missing: I couldn't remember the name of the principle!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a property of certain PDEs known as the [Maximum Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_principle). (See [these notes](http://www.math.ualberta.ca/~xinweiyu/527.1.09f/527_2009_lec06.pdf) (pdf warning) for its application to the heat equation.)

The maximum principle states that any solution $u(x,t)$ of the heat equation in a region of $(x,t)$ must have its extrema (minimum and maximum values) on the boundary of that region.

In this case, the region is $(x,t)\in[0,1]×[0,\infty)$. The boundary of this region has three parts: On $(x=0,t>0)$ the solution is fixed at 2. On $(x=1,t>0)$ the solution is fixed at 3. On $(x,t=0)$ the maximum value of 4 occurs at $x=1$. Thus 4 is the maximum value of u(x,t) which occurs on the boundary. By the maximum principle 4 is therefore the maximum value for *all* $x$ and $t$.

So $u(x,t) = 10$ cannot occur for any $x$ and $t$.

Answer (score 2):

The "Maximum Principle" is a very useful tool to answer to such a question (as John Barber rightly did). I will not come back with this principle to repeat what was already said and which is more general for all times from $t=0$ to $t\to\infty$.

In the present case, since the wording of the question concerns only $t\to\infty$ and where it is not question of the intermediate times, it is sufficient to observe that : 
$$u(x,t)=2+x+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} c_{n}e^{-n^{2}\pi^{2}kt}\sin(n\pi x)$$
tends to :
$$u(x,\infty)=2+x$$
because $e^{-n^{2}\pi^{2}k\:\infty}=0$

So, after a long time, the temperature profile tends to become linear, from $2$ (at $x=0$) to $3$ (at $x=1$).
$$2\leq u(x,\infty)\leq 3$$

NOTE :

(For information, of no use to answer to the question)

In the above equation, the condition $u(x,0)=x^2+x+2$ in not taken into account.

In order to compute the values of the coefficients $c_n$ :
$$u(x,0)=2+x+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} c_{n} \sin(n\pi x)=x^2+x+2$$
$$x^2=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} c_{n} \sin(n\pi x)$$
This is a Fourier series which coefficients are :
$$c_n=2\int_0^1 x^2\sin(n\pi x)dx= 4\frac{(-1)^n-1}{\pi^3n^3}-2\frac{(-1)^n}{n\pi}$$
$$u(x,t)=2+x+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(4\frac{(-1)^n-1}{\pi^3n^3}-2\frac{(-1)^n}{n\pi} \right)e^{-n^{2}\pi^{2}kt}\sin(n\pi x)$$